Nodetool repair --full -- takes a lot /data space after upgrading Cassandra 3.1 --> 4.1
The Cassandra was upgraded from version 3.1 to 4.1.
Each time after running nodetool full repair, the /data disk space significantly increases.
I am not sure what might be the reason.
